# Error when trying to set Dataflow AutoAdjustBufferSize in BIML

Tags: biml

I am trying to set the AutoAdjustBufferSize attribute within a BIML file but when I try to compile I get error messages when I try to set it as the attribute of the Dataflow component or if I try to set it as an expression.

This is the BIML file contents:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="TestPackage">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT - Test">
                    <Expressions>
                        <Expression PropertyName="AutoAdjustBufferSize">True</Expression>
                    </Expressions>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

And the error message I get is:

```
Could not resolve reference to 'AutoAdjustBufferSize' in property 'Property'. 'PropertyName="AutoAdjustBufferSize"' is invalid. Provide valid scoped name. Property Property.   D:\temp\TestAutoAdjustBufferSize.biml   7   26
Parse. There were errors during compilation. See compiler output for more information.
```

However, the BIML documentation shows it as an attribute of Dataflow - https://varigence.com/Documentation/Language/Element/AstDataflowTaskNode

I'm using Varigence BimlExpress 2016 - Build 5.0.60425.0

Anyone got any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Update your [BimlExpress](https://varigence.com/bimlexpress) - there was a [defect](https://varigence.com/Documentation/BimlExpress/Article/BimlExpress+2018) with the emitted SSIS for AutoAdjustBufferSize fixed in 5.0.63501